# Invoke a function with parameter as a string

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I need to invoke a function with parameter as a string. Look at the eg given below : Note that `"method(parameter1,parameter2)"` is enclosed with `""`.

```
string methodName = "method(3,4)"
string f = methodName ;

public string method(int one, int two){
    return "hi";
}
```

Above is the expected result. I will be invoking  a function with a string method name followed its parameters:

What I have tried so far:

1. I have tried using Reflection, but it didn't call the method.
2. How can I fix this ?

Is there any other way to do this ?

```
Type type = typeof(MyClass);
var method = type.GetMethod("method");
MyClass  cc = new MyClass();
string re= (string) method.Invoke(cc, new object[] {1,3});
```

Comment: `GetMethod` expects a method name. You would have to separate your method name and parameters, and then pass your parameters to `Invoke`. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @john I guess the parameters expect an Object array. It still doesn't get passed to the method. Help

Comment: Are you saying `type.GetMethod("method").Invoke(cc, new object[] { 3, 4 })` doesn't work? Can you explain how? Is `method` null?

Comment: I have updated my post. please have a look

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://rextester.com/LPWS22110)

Comment: Yes. it works. One of the method parameters were a string. Duh!. Thanks

Comment: @john Just wondering if there is any other approach I could take to invoke a function where it is written as "method(1,2)" ?

Comment: Essentially you need to split the method name from the parameters, and then split the individual parameters. The tricky part is converting the parameters to the correct C# types. Once you've done all of that, you can put the parameters in a `List<object>` and pass it to the `Invoke` method as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can invoke a method using reflection.

If you want to handle input to the method as part of the string, you have to parse that part of the string and pass the values as instances in the object array when you invoke the method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m = typeof(Program).GetMethod("PrintValue");
        var i  = new Program();
        m.Invoke(i, BindingFlags.Default, null, new object[] {42}, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }

    public void PrintValue(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```